# Not able to health check of service which is outside the cluster in prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-health-check

I have setup prometheus and blackbox to monitor the kubenetes cluster and it is working fine for the dservice monitoring that is probe success for all services fine but the services which are from outside, I am not able to monitor those one. For ex: google.com, its giving probe_status: 0 and probe_http_redirects:0

Blackbox targets array is:

```
   {
   "targets": [ "google.com" ],
   "labels": {
       "job": "kubernetes-services",
       "namespace": "default"
   }
```

}

Job:

```
- job_name: 'kubernetes-services'
  scheme: http
  metrics_path: /probe
  params:
    module: [http_2xx]
  file_sd_configs:
    - files:
      - /etc/prometheus/blackbox-targets.json
  relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__address__]
    target_label: __param_target
    replacement: ${1}
  - source_labels: [__param_target]
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: instance
    replacement: ${1}
  - source_labels: []
   regex: .*
   target_label: __address__
   replacement: mo-blackbox.mo-system:9115
```

Result:

```
probe_ip_protocol 6
probe_http_status_code 0
probe_http_content_length 0
probe_http_redirects 0
probe_http_ssl 0
probe_duration_seconds 0.373322
probe_success 0
```

I want probe_success and probe_http_redirects should be 1, how can I achieve it?

Comment: Looks like a firewall or routing issue. Can you reach these services from a curl or wget connection?

Comment: I found issue and fixed as well, it was an icinga configuration issue.